# Changing a model programming. How it works?

Tags: assembly, cpu, hardware

Please, explain me something. If I know correctly every CPU have a different programmming model. Let's suppose, that I have the CPU which can perform XYZ assembly instruction. Then I will compile program and send it to my friend, which have CPU without the XYZ assembly instrucion. Despite of this fact I think program will work. How it is made that once compiled program is generally independent from the hardware architecture?

Comment: How do you expect `XYZ` to work on a CPU which does not implement the instruction?

Comment: It likely uses the very common x86 instruction set (obviously expanded with some additions, but also some common ones). Please try to move a program compiled on an AMD processor (the older the better) to an Intel processor (of the same time period). The last time I tried it it didn't work because the compiler used some AMD-specific instructions during the optimization.

Comment: It will not work.  In spite of what you learned in school, nobody actually writes programs in assembly.  At a minimum you use C and use a compiler that generates the machine code that's appropriate for the specific platform.

Comment: _"Despite of this fact I think program will work."_ It won't, unless you explicitly check whether the host system supports instruction XYZ and take an alternative code path that does the same thing but without that instruction in case it isn't supported.

Comment: The program will work in your friend's computer (that does not implement XYZ instruction) only if a) your program does not use XYZ instruction at all, or b) the execution of the program in your friend's computer never reaches XYZ instruction, or c) in your friend's CPU there is another instruction of exactly same encoding as XYZ in your CPU, and both cause same effects in the your code, or the effects are irrelevant for the execution of the program.

Comment: **How it is made that once compiled program is generally independent from the hardware architecture?** It's just the opposite! Compilation makes it (more) hardware dependant.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for anserws, but I was a little imprecise in my question. So let's suppose I have an AMD processor and my friend has an Intel CPU. If I compile a C program and I will send it to my friend will it work ? Can GCC be forced to compile something using XYZ instruction ? Can GCC be forbidden to use this instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course a binary will only be able to execute on a machine of the architecture it was compiled for. You can't run an ARM executable on x86, for example. Most times, the program loader won't even let you try.

We are able to successfully distribute binary versions of software (for a particular architecture, like x86-64), because there is a base set of instructions which that processor must support. Your Intel CPU and your buddy's AMD CPU still both implement the same basic instruction set. By default, GCC will only emit instructions that fall into this category.

In addition, GCC can be allowed to emit more specialized instructions, which fall into a particular instruction set *extension*. For example, there are various iterations of the SSE extensions, which perform vector math. Because not all CPUs implement these instructions, you must explicitly tell GCC that it is allowed to use them. You can do this with the `-march` and `-mtune` flags to GCC. `-march=native` will compile a program to work well for your machine, but might not work if you try to run that same binary on another machine with a different CPU.

While that strategy works well if your code is going to be compiled, we can implement a kind of hybrid approach. This involves using the `CPUID` instruction to determine (at run-time) what features of interest are available on the current CPU. Then, based on that information, we can make calls to different functions which utilize different instruction set extensions. These would typically be hand-coded in assembly, or in C using the [built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html) for the architecture in question.

The Linux kernel actually does this at run-time as well, although often in a more impressive fashion. A couple examples on x86:

- In [SMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) systems, the x86 `LOCK` prefix is required on certain  instructions to prevent multiple CPUs from simultaneously modifying the same variables. On uniprocessor (UP) systems however, this instruction is unnecessary and slows things down. If a kernel compiled for SMP determines that it is running on a UP system, it will actually `NOP`-out the `LOCK` instruction, rendering it useless. That is, it writes a "no-op" instruction over top.
- String instructions can be given a `REP` prefix to operate over a region of memory. For example, `REP STOSB` can be used to implement `memset` while `REP MOVSB` can be used for `memcpy`, and so on. Well over the years, various Intel processors have internally implemented these instructions much differently. Because of this, the Linux kernel will determine if the CPU it is running on has a "good" implementation or not (again based upon `CPUID`). If it is good, it will use the `REP ...` instructions. If not, an alternate routine is used.
- Kernels compiled with [paravirtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization) support also do this for privileged instructions. A kernel running on bare metal is able to execute the `LGDT` instruction, while a kernel running under Xen must make a [hypercall](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Hypercall) to the hypervisor to accomplish the same.
- All of these capabilities are exposed via the `flags :` line in `/proc/cpuinfo`. The list is quite long these days.